# Instapy issue: "inappropriate, user_name, is_video, reason, scope = check_link()...", how to solve?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, instagram-api, instapy

I've downloaded the last version of Instapy, and put it on C:\Users\adriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages , but always when I run a simple like_by_tag script or any other like script happen this issue:

**inappropriate, user_name, is_video, reason, scope = check_link()**

I don't know how can I solve it, didn't find good solutions for this.

Anyone has already solved this error before, It looks that this newer version of InstaPy there are many issues to be fixed?

```
# session
session = InstaPy(username=userInfo['username'], password=userInfo['password'])
session.login()
# comments
session.set_do_comment(enabled=True, percentage= int(probability))
session.set_comments(comentarios, media='Photo')
# likes
session.set_do_like(enabled=True, percentage=100)
session.like_by_tags([tag], amount=int(total))
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of instagram source code changes. You have to change the code as below:

File : instapy/like_util.py , Line: 619

```
    media = post_page['items'][0]
    is_video = media["is_unified_video"]
    user_name = media["user"]["username"]
    image_text = media["caption"]["text"]
    owner_comments = ""
```